# React Table Pagination

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react js. We used `react-table` to display the records in the tabular format.
The issue which I am facing is pagination is not working.
To enable the pagination in `react-table`, set the props according to the documentation i.e.

```
<ReactTable
   manual
   className="expandableTable -highlight"
   columns={this.props.column}
   data={this.state.data}
   showPagination={true}
   minRow={5}
   defaultSortDesc={true}
   ref={this.props.id}
   defaultPageSize={5}
   multiSort={false}
   ...
```

Any suggestion, what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these to you code. and this.props.onFetch is a custom method whenever you will change the page it will go into this.props.onFetch method. i hope this helps.

```
 onPageChange={(pageIndex) => { // Called when the page index is changed by the user
              this.setState({
                currentPageIndex: pageIndex
              });
              this.props.onFetchPage(this.props.status, pageIndex, this.state.pageSize, this.state.sorted);
            }}

onPageSizeChange={(pageSize, pageIndex) => {
          this.setState({
            pageSize: pageSize
          })
          this.props.onFetchPage(this.props.status, 0, pageSize, this.state.sorted);
        }}
```